# What determines the cadence that a readable Node stream emits data?

Tags: javascript, stream

If I configure a stream to emit the contents of a file, what is actually determining the rate at which chunks are read from source and sent to the destination (maybe another stream, for example)?

Also: is it correct terminology to say "chunks" of data to refer to the slices of data read and processed in a sequential fashion to avoid reading everything in at once.